# jQuery.inArray keeps returning -1

Tags: jquery

**EDIT** jQuery.inArray kept failing to do string != int comparisons, and this was resolved with the help of ShankarSongoli.  Originally it was thought to be a variable scope issue, so please remember to look at all aspects and not just one in any given problem.

```
   omit_all_user_contacts = new Array();
    add_contacts = new Array();

    function is_added_contact(id) {
        if ( jQuery.inArray(id, add_contacts) == -1 )
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    function selectcontacts(userid){
      document.getElementById("ic"+userid).checked = true;
      omit_all_user_contacts.push(userid);
      var buf = '<table class="contactlist" width="100%">';
      buf = buf + "<tr class='contactlistheader'><td></td><td>Contact Name</td><td>Company</td><td>Email</td><td>Profession</td></tr>";
      var tmp;
      jQuery.getJSON('/user/get_user_contacts/'+userid, function(data) {

          jQuery.each(data.contacts, function(key, value) {

            buf = buf + "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='manualcontact[]' onclick='manualcontact(" + value.id + ",this.checked)' ";
                alert(is_added_contact(value.id)); 

            if ( jQuery.inArray(value.id, add_contacts) > -1 ) {

                buf = buf + " checked ";
            }
            buf = buf + "/></td>";
            buf = buf + "<td>" + value.firstname + " " + value.lastname + "</td>";
            buf = buf + "<td>" + value.company + "</td>";
            buf = buf + "<td>" + value.email + "</td>";
            buf = buf + "<td>" + value.profession + "</td></tr>";
          });
          buf = buf + '</table>';
          iBox.show(buf);
      }); 
    }

    function manualcontact(id,val) {
        if ( val == true ) {
            add_contacts.push(id);
        } else {
            add_contacts.splice( jQuery.inArray(val, add_contacts), 1 );
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try it again with using `var` for both the variables. What error do you get?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response.  When manualcontact is called, the value is added to the add_contacts array.  However, when selectcontacts is called, the add_contacts array disappears once it starts this loop: jQuery.each(data.contacts, function(key, value), but in the previous line, this variable IS visible, I just need it to be accessible within the each statement as well.

Comment: Since it is a global variable it will he accessible inside `each` loop also.

Comment: I wish that were true in this case, but is not...
I also just tried a workaround I really thought would work,by setting  `tmpContacts = add_contacts;` in the line before the `each` loop. However, `tmpContacts` is also, inaccessible from within the each statement. :(

Comment: What do you mean by inaccessible? Do you get error when code execution reaches that point?

Comment: Actually, the issue does not actually seem to be with scope.  Sorry for the confusion. The statement `jQuery.inArray(value.id, tmpContacts)` returns -1, however the length of tmpContacts is 1 and inside it contains value.id (which is 2 in my testing), and that's why I thought it was an issue with the scope

Comment: This is text from an alert call that I used and it's boggling my mind...

`jQuery.inArray(2,tmpContacts) = -1; tmpContacts.length = 1; tmpContacts[0] = 2`

Comment: May be `tmpContacts[0]` contains `"2"` as a string type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the title of the question first and also since the issue is resolved through our comments accept this answer and close it.

**Solution:**

The array values were of string type and comparison was done with integers, so it was failing.

```
var tmpContacts = ["2"];
jQuery.inArray(2, tmpContacts) was always returning `-1`
```

Change it to `jQuery.inArray("2", tmpContacts)`

Answer (score 0):

It is important that the type of the variable is the same. I needed to compare integers, but since my original text contained numbers split by commas then the items in my array were being seen as strings.

Here was a simple function I wrote to check for integers only.
It works the same as jquery.inArray but it only checks a specific data type.

```
function in_array(val,arr) {
    cnt=0;
    index=-1;
    $(arr).each(function () {
        if(parseInt(this) == parseInt(val)) { index=cnt; }
        cnt++;
    });
    return index;
}
```